# 2 Dimensional Arrays.Why do I have to declare size of Columns in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to ask a question about 2D arrays in C .First Let me explain what I want to do.

I am trying to read names into a 2D array till user enters 0 and from that array I want to randomly pick an name. Now I have couple of questions.

Why do I have to declare the size of `arr`? I want to do it like `char arr[][50]` the reason that am asking this is because I took a semester of C before my current semester and I remember my tutor said something like you don't have to declare size of column as long as you declare a row size.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char arr[50][50];
    int i;
    for(i= 0 ; i < 50; i++){
        scanf("%s",&arr[i]);  
    }
}
```

I just found that I was missing braces after if inside for code gives no error at the moment but entering 0 from the keyboard does not executes the proccess.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char arr[0][50];
    int i;
    for(i= 0 ; i < 50; i++){
        scanf("%49s", arr[i]);
        if(arr[i]== 0){
            arr[i][0] = '\0';
            break;}

    }
}
```

Also I want to read names in a function but couldn't figure out how to pass the `arr[50][50]` to a function So I can read names in that function.

I am trying to work with ANSI C

Comment: `if(arr[i]= 0)` => `if(arr[i]==0)` ?? but `arr[i]` is a char array, you cannot assign to an integer

Comment: Which element of the 2D array are you expecting `arr[i] = '\0';` to modify?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&arr[i]);` => `scanf("%49s",arr[i]);`

Comment: `scanf("%s",&arr[i]);` is incorrect.  Use `scanf("%s",arr[i]);` instead.  Remember, `scanf` expects a `char *` for strings, not a `char (*)[50]`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ith row of the array

Comment: But which column?

Comment: Also, a declaration like `char arr[][50]` is ok for formal function arguments, in which case it is adjusted to `char (*arr)[50]` by the compiler.  But you obviously can't do that when declaring it as a local (or global) variable, since otherwise the compiler has no idea how much space to allocate.

Comment: Assigning an integer value such as 0 to a character variable is true in C.

Comment: C is a column base language, in two dimention array you must express column size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create something in a program, you need to know how big it is. The computer has to decide what memory it is going to store the thing in, so it has to know how much memory it needs. So, when you define an array, you must include all the sizes. So, in `char arr[50][50];`, both of the dimension lengths are needed.

When you pass an array to a function, the function does not always need to know how big the array is. It only needs to know where the array is and where its parts are. Once you tell the function where the array is and what the parts are, the function has the information it needs (because it can calculate how big each part is from knowing what type they are).

In C, we could have said, when you pass an array to a function, declare the type (so the function understands the parts the array is made of) and pass the address of the array. Instead, they did something slightly different. They decided, when you pass an array to a function, you declare the type and pass the address of the first element. (On a lot of computer processors, these two addresses are the same thing at the machine language level. But there can be differences.)

So, when you pass this array `arr` to a function, you are supposed to pass `&arr[0]`, which is the address of the first element of `arr`. (Note that `arr` is an array of 50 arrays of 50 `char`. So **its** elements are arrays of 50 `char`. In contrast, `&arr[0][0]` is the address of the first element of the first element of `arr`.)

That would work fine. Everybody could pass `&arr[0]` or whatever the first element of their array is. But the creators of C decided to make it look simpler and to look like you were passing the array. They made a rule that if you use `arr` in a typical expression, the compiler would automatically convert it to `&arr[0]` for you. So you can write `MyFunction(arr)`, and it is just like you wrote `MyFunction(&arr[0])`.

Next, what does the array look like in the function declaration? Since you are passing a pointer to the first element of the array, you ought to declare that as `char (*arr)[50]`, which is a pointer to an array of 50 `char`. However, again, the creators of C wanted to make this look better, so they said, in a function declaration, you can declare a parameter as `char arr[50][50]`, and the compiler will automatically adjust it to be `char (*arr)[50]`. Whenever you declare a function parameter to be an array, the compiler automatically adjusts the declared type to be a pointer to an element. (This adjustment only occurs for the first dimension.)

So, when you pass an array to a function, the function actually receives a pointer to the first element. Then, if it ever wants to find the element with index *n*, all it has to do is add the size of *n* elements to the address of the first element. So the function has all the information it needs to locate array elements. It does not need to know the total size. If you write `arr[3][4]` in the function, the function starts with the address you passed. Then it calculates where element 3 is, which is 3 times the size of an element. An element of `arr` is an array of 50 `char`, so its size is 50. So `arr[3]` is at the start address plus 150 bytes. Then it calculates where element 4 of that array is, which is 4 times the size of an element. An element of `arr[3]` is a `char`, so its size is 1. So `arr[3][4]` is at the start address plus 150 bytes plus 4 bytes.

Since a function does not actually need to know the total size of the array, you are allowed to declare a function parameter with `char arr[][50]`, leaving out the length of the first dimension. The compiler would just discard that length anyway when it adjusts the parameter to `char (*)[50]`.

Comment: The address of an array and that of its first element are *always* different in that they have different types.  Those types may or may not have different representations.  On the other hand, the addresses are always the same in that they represent the same storage location.  Arrays have no padding.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: If you are referring to the phrase “On a lot of computer processors,” it is talking about hardware addresses at that point, not addresses in C implementations.

Comment: In that sense, then, no, there *cannot* be differences.  In a conforming C implementation, the representation of an array begins with the representation of its first element, ends with the representation of its last element, and contains no padding between elements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, there can be differences. The fact that two hardware addresses are composed of differently valued bits (or numbers of them) does not mean they point to different places in memory. One example is on word-oriented computers, in which the fundamental hardware address is the number of the word in memory, and the address of the array is simply the word address, but, in order to implement character arrays, the software must join the word address with additional bits.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook what you meant by "hardware addresses".  It would be less open to misunderstanding in a C-specific discussion if you used C's standard terminology (i.e. different pointer types may have different *representations*).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I have updated it to refer to addresses at machine language level. I appreciate that the C standard uses different terminology, but it does that as an abstraction to divorce it from specific hardware, and I think trying to teach that abstraction at this level is harder.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer - but probably help you to develop code better

> I just found that i was missing braces after if inside for code gives
>   no error at the moment but entering 0 from the keyboard does not
>   executes the procces.

If i understand correctly, you want to exit the application when you type 0. If so the condition `if(arr[i]== 0)` would not work. When you type 0 , the it stores its ASCII value in the character array. To tell compiler you are looking for ASCII 0, you need use '0'.

Now how entered value stored on to arr[50][50].

For the first iteration i=0 , and you entered abcd(hit enter) -> 
arr[0][0] = 'a', arr[0][1] = 'b' arr[0][2] = 'c', arr[0][3] = 'd' and arr[0][4] ='\0'

for second iteration i =1 and you entered   mnop(hit enter) ->
arr[1][0] = 'm', arr[1][1] = 'n' arr[1][2] = 'o', arr[1][3] = 'p' and arr[1][4] ='\0'
and so on

To exit application when you type 0, you can probably use `if(arr[i][0]== '0')` condition. But this condition will not work in all cases, it works only if the first character you typed (after you hit enter which means it is stepping up to next array location) is 0